# MeteorJS - event click after template.onRendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I've got a template that I want to add a click event to with Meteor.template.event(). Problem is that the .event() is not working right and I can't get a hold of the DOM.

Im using Meteor.template.onRendered() to display API data and I'm using jQuery to shove the data into the template. Then I want to grab a [name] selector that was generated through jQuery and manipulate it with Meteor.template.event() but it's not working

```
//server Meteor.method()
incrementNormalPoints: function(err){
  Points.upsert( {userId: this.userId}, { $inc : {normalPoints : 2} });
}

//client Meteor.template.onRendered().. this part works 
Template.normalMode.onRendered(function(){
  $("[name=imageGuess").append('<div class="flip"><div name="imageCard" class="card"><div class="face front"><img name="rightAnswer" id="theImg" class="img-responsive" src="'+imgArray[i]+'" /></div><div class="face back"><span class="center-glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></div></div></div>');
}

Template.normalMode.events({
  "click [name=rightAnswer]" : function(){
     event.preventDefault();
     Meteor.call("incrementNormalPoints");
     console.log("hello");
  }
});
```

Hope I made sense. At the moment the console log in the events() function isn't working either. I'm pretty sure it's because of the DOM not "existing" and JS can't get a hold of it.

Comment: Is there any way to insert your HTML through Blaze in your template instead of using `onRendered`?

Comment: Why do not you create a separate function for whatever you want to do in the event, and call that function both from event and from `onRendered`?

Comment: @chazsolo I'm pretty new to meteor. I'm doing jQuery because I'm randomely generating images from the API I'm using and shoving them into the DOM. It's not static. Is there a link you know about where I could learn more?

Petr do you mean a helper function?

Comment: What @Petr is saying, I think, is using a `helper` to call the API and gather the images and return them so you can iterate over them in Blaze

Comment: I don't know if this is a good idea but if you guys head over to my [repo](https://github.com/dannyk08/WT_Memory_Game) you'll see my code. 

I'm using an algorithm to randomize image in the API, put them into an array, and then shove them in the template with jquery. I'm not sure if this is the answer you were looking for

Comment: I mean to have separate function not related to a template -- a free-standing function, or a method of a separate class, etc. The function will do the work you need. I can't look into your code right now, but in your example from the question you can move the `Meteor.call` and `console.log` to a free-standing function, and call this function both from the event and `onRendered`.

Comment: Or do you simply want to set, not call, an event handler in the `onRendered`?

Comment: I'll give your suggestion a try, I figured that since I defined a method that I had to follow it with a Meteor.event() function call call the declared method in the server. Thank you for your help Petr I'll show the answer if it works!

Comment: the event is ```"click [name=imageGuess] [name=rightAnswer]":function(){..}```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found a workaround to this problem and it works. Which is all I want at the moment. I overlooked Meteor.events() completely and worked through the Meteor.onRendered() block.

I made a function upsertNPoints() that "calls" my declared method on the server and uses it to upsert points to my points table.

```
//server Methods()
incrementNormalPoints: function(err){
Points.upsert( {userId: this.userId}, { $inc : {normalPoints : 2} });
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}
},

//Upsert database using the call() method meteor provides on the client
function upsertNPoints(){
  $("[name=rightAnswer]").on("click", function(){
    Meteor.call("incrementNormalPoints");
    location.reload(true);//this is just to reload the window after a click
  });
}

upsertNPoints();
```

Hope this helps any one with this weird issue I had. Thanks for your suggestions @Petr and @chazsolo